# Setting Turkish and English locale: translate Turkish characters to Latin equivalents

Tags: java, android, locale

I want to translate my Turkish strings to lowercase in both English and Turkish locale. I'm doing this:

```
String myString="YAŞAT BAYRI";
Locale trlocale= new Locale("tr-TR");
Locale enLocale = new Locale("en_US");

Log.v("mainlist", "en source: " +myString.toLowerCase(enLocale));
Log.v("mainlist", "tr source: " +myString.toLowerCase(trlocale));
```

The output is:

```
en source: yaşar bayri

tr source: yaşar bayri
```

But I want to have an output like this:

```
en source: yasar bayri

tr source: yaşar bayrı
```

Is this possible in Java?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you are using the `Locale` constructor, you can and must set the language, country and variant as separate arguments:

```
new Locale(language)
new Locale(language, country)
new Locale(language, country, variant)
```

Therefore, your test program creates locales with the language "tr-TR" and "en_US". For your test program, you can use `new Locale("tr", "TR")` and `new Locale("en", "US")`.

If you are using Java 1.7+, then you can also parse a language tag using `Locale.forLanguageTag`:

```
String myString="YASAT BAYRI";
Locale trlocale= Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR");
Locale enLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("en_US");
```

Creates strings that have the appropriate lower case for the language.

Answer (score 11):

I think this is the problem:

```
Locale trlocale= new Locale("tr-TR");
```

Try this instead:

```
Locale trlocale= new Locale("tr", "TR");
```

That's the constructor to use to specify country and language.

Comment: new Locale("tr") would actually be enough, since the capitalization rules for the Turkish language are independent of the country.

Answer (score 5):

you can do that:

```
Locale trlocale= new Locale("tr","TR");
```

The first parameter is your language, while the other one is your country.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the string in ASCII, without accents, the following might do.
First an accented character might be split in ASCII char and a combining diacritical mark (zero-width accent). Then only those accents may be removed by regular expression replace.

```
public static String withoutDiacritics(String s) {
    // Decompose any ş into s and combining-,.
    String s2 = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    return s2.replaceAll("(?s)\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}", "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Characters `ş` and `s` are different characters. Changing locale cannot help you to translate one to another. You have to create turkish-to-english characters table and do this yourself. I once did this for Vietnamic language that has a lot of such characters. You have to deal with 4 of 5, right? So, good luck!